# Bundle product how check mode(grid/list) in price.phtml

Tags: magento

I wonder how can I check that we have grid or list in

```
\template\bundle\catalog\product\price.phtml
```

I would like set a format price depending on mode(grid/list), in list.phtml we can check type of mode by

```
<?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
```

but in price.phtml this method didn't work
thx for help

Comment: $_GET['mode'] will contain the mode, if it's not set it's the default mode (depending on your configuration). If it's not clean enough and you only use 1 mode, you can have this through getStoreConfig or with Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List getMode() method ;)

Comment: Thx for help, $_GET['mode'] fix my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_GET['mode'] will contain the mode, if it's not set it's the default mode (depending on your configuration). If it's not clean enough and you only use 1 mode, you can have this through getStoreConfig or with Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List getMode() method ;)